# How to make printf output INT_MAX

Tags: c

I was wondering how to make printf function output int_max. If an input goes over 1.5 billion the output stays the same at approximately 1 billion. On the platform I work with INT_MAX is 2.17 billion so I know that this is definitely within the bounds of an int.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "hw02.h"

int Pow(int a, int b);

int main( int argc, const char* argv[] )
{
    printf("%d", pow(2147483647,1));
}

int Pow(int a, int b){
    if(b<0){
        return (1/a) * Pow(a ,b-1);
    }
    else if (b==0) {
        return 1;
    }
    else if (b==1){
        return a;
    }
    else{
        return a * Pow(a,b-1);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your reason for using the "_" in `_Pow` ?

Comment: If `a` is an `int` then `1/a` is either 0 or a division-by-0 fault. Just sayin'

Comment: @Yunnosch - I wanted to specify it as a helper function called solely within this file

Comment: @rici - that's a great point I'll make sure to add a check at the beginning so that the radix/input base will not be zero in order to avoid the division-by-zero fault

Comment: Skip the habit of using "_" at the beginning of identifiers. Sooner or later you will get in trouble.

Comment: @Yunnosch - I went ahead and fixed the name

Comment: `_` followed by an Uppercase letter is, in fact, reserved for the C implementation!

Comment: *"All identifiers that begin with an underscore and either an uppercase letter or another underscore are **always reserved for any use.**"*

Comment: If you want a file-local function, make it `static`.

Comment: Note that `buffer` is unsigned, yet you assign it to the value of (signed) `n`. That makes the line `buffer = -buffer;` nonsensical.

Comment: @tim: in C, the unary minus operator can be applied to an unsigned argument; the result is well-defined. It is unsigned if the argument is at least as wide as an `unsigned int` and its value is one more than the bitwise inverse of the argument. By contrast, `-a` where `a` is `signed int` may be UB if tge value of `a` is `INT_MIN` and `int`s are 2s-complement.

Comment: "I'd like to know how to make this function without a static array: baseDigs in my case." --> the array is avoidable if code _assumes_ the character encoding like ASCII.

Comment: Note: `return -1;` is an error to return a -1 in a  `void print_integer()` function.

Comment: `_Pow()` is not defined making code uncompilable.

Comment: **Please do not deface your post.**

Comment: "On the platform I work with INT_MAX is 2.17 billion so I know that this is definitely within the bounds of an int." - `INT_MAX` is by definition **always** and `int`,hence within the limits of `int`. That's the idea of that macro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the result of your `Pow` function: the return type is `int` (probably 32 bit), and an overflow is occuring. I'm going to use `int32_t` (defined in `stdint.h`) throughout this, assuming your system has 32 bit integers (most desktop computers do, but if this is for an embedded system that might not be the case), to make it clear where the problem is.

You're using `Pow` to get the next power of 10 after `n`, however for values close to INT32_MAX (in particular any value after 1,000,000,000, which is the first power of ten less than `INT32_MAX`) the next power of 10 isn't representable as an `int32_t` (because `10,000,000,000 > INT32_MAX`) leading to an overflow (I believe the result is undefined, but in practice the value returned by `Pow` will most likely be `-(INT32_max-10,000,000,000)`).

So, you can fix this by increasing the number of bits used in the result of `Pow`, by having it return `int64_t` (or `long long int`, if you don't want to use `stdint.h`)

<s>Also don't forget to make `buffer` signed as I mentioned in my comment above. Your compiler should have caught that and emitted a warning, if not then you're probably not compiling with all warnings enabled. In some (most?) compilers this is enabled by passing the flag `-Wall` to it.</s>

### Edit:

See chux's comment regarding why making `buffer` signed is not the right solution (using `unsigned` is fully-defined and works). Consider using `int64_t` throughout to avoid overflow and type conversion anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the informative comment, it fixed the issue entirely

Comment: "don't forget to make buffer signed",  `buffer = -buffer;` and `n == INT_MIN` lead to undefined behavior.  OP's code does not have the defect.

Comment: @chux is there any reason to not make `buffer` signed?

Comment: As [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47732861/how-to-make-a-print-integer-function-without-printf-output-int-max/47733162?noredirect=1#comment82427430_47733162),  with signed `int` math, and `buffer` as signed, `buffer = -buffer;` when `buffer` has the value of `INT_MIN` is certainly undefined behavior.  To use `int` math other changes are needed to prevent that case.

Comment: Try changing `buffer` to `int` and run `print_integer(INT_MIN, 10, "");` and see what happens.  It is not good.

Comment: @chux thanks, I did not realize that would happen. I've removed that recommendation from my answer.

Comment: @chux I assumed the function prototype was fixed (i.e. it is only required to handle `int`s), thus OP could use the larger types as intermediate variables within the function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160863/discussion-between-chux-and-tim-sweet).